# displaying images Gallery from assets/images

Tags: java, android, image-gallery, imagelist

i would like to Display an image gallery but from "assets/images" folder not from the phone storage.

like this one:
 [image]

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. What is your question? If your question is "how do I do this?", please explain what you have tried and what specific problems you have encountered.

Comment: im asking to how to do it? ^_^ 
cause im new in android so im asking if someone can give me a way to do it

Comment: That's too broad. You should consider looking up some tutorials that will build you up to this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is not clear, if you want to load a single image from assets,
then you can do it this way.

```
//read image from asset
InputStream is = getAssets().open("image.jpg");

//    create a drawable
Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(is, null);

//find reference to your imageview and set drawable
ImageView i=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_id); 
i.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

Comment: i asked for displaying a gallery of images like the image i added so i dont think i need to display a single image ^_^
thank you anyway

Comment: add these to an ArrayList & add these drawables to it.use a GridView to display it.